# Submit App to Apple without the latest Xcode version

Tags: xcode4, submission

A read similar questions but related to `Beta version of Xcode`, my doubt is wired to the last version of Xcode (4.3) that seems to be too buggy at the moment!

I rather use Xcode 4.2 but I'm not sure I can submit apps with this version! Is the last version of Xcode  a requirement to send app to Apple ? 
Where I can read something about that ? Apple documentation didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still submit apps with xCode 4.2 . Only beta version of xCode cannot submit apps.